# Deploy Grails 3.1.1 to Heroku

Tags: grails, heroku, build.gradle, grails-3.1

I was using 3.0.14v Grails and I did some deployments to heroku. Everything was working fine, however I wanted to try with Grails 3.1.1 and I'm getting some errors now.

I was following this post https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-gradle-apps-on-heroku

I cloned this https://github.com/kissaten/grails3-example

I think it's something about tomcat version but not sure.

Any help?

[image: heroku logs]

[image: heroku logs]

Comment: What does your `Procfile` look like?

Comment: the Procfile:
"web: cd build ; java $JAVA_OPTS -Dgrails.env=prod -jar ../build/server/webapp-runner-*.jar --expand-war --port $PORT libs/*.war"

Comment: I tried using compile 'com.github.jsimone:webapp-runner:8.0.30.1' instead of 7.0.57.2  but I got an error: | Error Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':testRuntime'. Type 'gradle dependencies' for more information

I'm not sure if I'm missing something about Tomcat 8 config. Any thought ?

Answer (score 1):

For your trouble with the compile '*com.github.jsimone:webapp-runner:8.0.30.1*', I figured it out by removing the *httpclient* module from all test* import, and I imported a good version of that module (only for test*).

```
testCompile ("org.grails.plugins:geb"){
    exclude module: 'httpclient'
}
testCompile ('org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-firefox-driver:2.48.2'){
    exclude module: 'httpclient'
}
testCompile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.5'
```

Thanks to that, I could import the "last" webapp-runner (directly as a jar)

```
compile 'com.github.jsimone:webapp-runner:8.0.30.1@jar'
```

Maybe that version of the *webapp-runner* will fix the problem, but I'm not sure.
As I saw on your stacktraces, there is a NoClassDefFoundException for *org/apache/tomcat/util/descriptor/tld/TldParser*.

This class is provided by the **tomcat-embed-core** artifact. And that artifact comes from **spring-boot-starter-tomcat** (as a dependency). Change "spring-boot-starter-tomcat" from provided to compiled or try another version (for Grails 3.0.9, the spring-starter-tomcat version is 1.2.6).

Hope it helps ;)

Answer (score 1):

I'm unsure of the specifics, but it looks like Grails 3.1.1 requires some of the classes in the Tomcat 8.x line.

I found a solution
I used a "compile 'com.github.jsimone:webapp-runner:8.0.30.2'" instead '8.0.30.1' and It's working well now.

I think there is an issue with including '8.0.30.1' as a compile time dependency.